# composer php cli has stopped working

Tags: php, composer-php

I have tried to install with following command laravel / lumen:

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0"
```

But my commandline ends with an error: "CLI has stopped working" in my windows event-log is following entry:

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: php.exe, Version: 5.6.8.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5553b22c
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: php5ts.dll, Version: 5.6.8.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5553b2a2
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x0004a5ec
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x1168
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d1247012bc4f0e
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: D:\Applications\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8\php.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: D:\Applications\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8\php5ts.dll
Berichtskennung: e7132df8-3deb-4564-9ee1-9b7e15010821
Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets: 
Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist: ...
```

I search for a solutions via google but nothing found - nothing worked for me

kind regards

Comment: if you type `which composer` in the cli, what do you get?

Comment: Try running the command with high verbosity - it will provide more detailed description of process: `composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0" -vvv`.

Comment: which composer does not work -> composer 1.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

If i am typing "composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0" -vvv"

```
D:\workspace>composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0" -vvv
Changed current directory to C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): hg branch
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): svn info --xml
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): hg branch
Executing command (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer): svn info --xml
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-01.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-04.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-07.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-10.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-laravel$lumen-installer.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzlehttp$guzzle.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$console.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$process.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzlehttp$streams.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzlehttp$ringphp.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-react$promise.json from cache
Analyzed 626 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 7133 rules to resolve dependencies
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.7.7)
```